# Notation for all of the integer divisors of a number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What is / is there a notation for the set that consists of all of the integer divisors of an integer. For example:
$$[7]=\{1, 7\}$$
$$[12]=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12\}$$
Note that I am using $[$ and $]$ in place of the notation that I am trying to find.

I am not looking for the set of all prime divisors, just the set of integer divisors.

Comment: If you're not looking for prime factors, consider calling them "divisors" to avoid any confusion

Comment: @vrugtehagel good idea. Fixed.

Comment: You could write $\mid n$, I suppose, since this set is the principal idea of $n$ in the poset under divisibility. The more general notation for the principal ideal in a partial order is $\downarrow n$, so you could write is as $\downarrow_{\mid} n$. But that looks horrible to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no widely used notation for this (at least, I have never encountered it, and couldn't fnd anything on wikipedia and mathworld.wolfram) - however there are functions and other notations to denote almost anything you can want to write down with that set. Let's for now denote the set of (positive) divisors of $n$ by $[n]$. The only two things I can think of that you'd want to write down with $[n]$ are the following, together with a more widely used alternative:
\begin{align}
d\in [n] &\Longleftrightarrow d\mid n \text{ (and } d>0\text{)}\\
\#[n]\text{ or } |[n]| &\Longleftrightarrow \tau(n)\text{ or }\sigma_0(n)
\end{align}
So in the end, you can define it, if you want (be cautious with your $[n]$-notation; people sometimes denote the floor function by that), but it's probably not that useful.